# google analytics in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I tried this:
https://github.com/msadouni/cakephp-plugin-google-analytics

It is a google analytics plugin.

Just not to sure where my Tracking ID should go. Which file do I place that in?

And if anyone could explain how to use this plugin a bit more, then that would be a great help.

If anyone has a better plugin please feel free to let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Documentation](https://github.com/msadouni/cakephp-plugin-google-analytics/blob/master/README.markdown) is pretty clear:

> Duplicate config/google_analytics.php.default into
>   config/google_analytics.php and fill your account information in
>   $google_analytics array.

Comment: @Dale As far as i know, `google_analytics` is the only supported value yes.

Comment: Thanks, so can you perhaps tell me if I need to use my Tracking ID anywhere in those files?

Comment: @dale https://github.com/msadouni/cakephp-plugin-google-analytics Again it's all in the documentation. `$this->GoogleAnalyticsAccount->find('all');` will retrieve all accounts. Then select the data you want.